# Contentsliding is not stopping at sysfolder since TYPO3 v10 - How to solve?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

The [TSref entry for `slide`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Content/Index.html#slide) explains:

> Up to Version 9 of TYPO3 the sliding stopped when reaching a folder.
> Beginning with TYPO3 10 this is not longer the case. See
> $cObj->checkPid_badDoktypeList.

Ok, this variable is still 255 (formerly directly, now via constant `PageRepository::DOKTYPE_RECYCLER`).

What exactly should I see there that will help me? Or better, how to get content sliding still working like before?

Answer (score 1):

You have to extend the ContentObjectRenderer class and overwrite the getSlidePids method with your own extension.

In the boot function of ext_localconf.php:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects'][\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer::class] = [
        'className' => \YourVendor\YourExtensionKey\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer::class
    ];
```

Then you have to create your own "Classes/ContentObject/ContentObjectRenderer.php" with:

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the TYPO3 CMS project.
 *
 * It is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under
 * the terms of the GNU General Public License, either version 2
 * of the License, or any later version.
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please read the
 * LICENSE.txt file that was distributed with this source code.
 *
 * The TYPO3 project - inspiring people to share!
 */

namespace YourVendor\YourExtension\ContentObject;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Domain\Repository\PageRepository;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;

class ContentObjectRenderer extends \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer
{

    /**
     * Returns all parents of the given PID (Page UID) list
     *
     * @param string $pidList A list of page Content-Element PIDs (Page UIDs) / stdWrap
     * @param array $pidConf stdWrap array for the list
     * @return string A list of PIDs
     * @internal
     */
    public function getSlidePids($pidList, $pidConf)
    {
        // todo: phpstan states that $pidConf always exists and is not nullable. At the moment, this is a false positive
        //       as null can be passed into this method via $pidConf. As soon as more strict types are used, this isset
        //       check must be replaced with a more appropriate check like empty or count.
        $pidList = isset($pidConf) ? trim($this->stdWrap($pidList, $pidConf)) : trim($pidList);
        if ($pidList === '') {
            $pidList = 'this';
        }
        $tsfe = $this->getTypoScriptFrontendController();
        $listArr = null;
        if (trim($pidList)) {
            $listArr = GeneralUtility::intExplode(',', str_replace('this', (string)$tsfe->contentPid, $pidList));
            $listArr = $this->checkPidArray($listArr);
        }
        $pidList = [];
        if (is_array($listArr) && !empty($listArr)) {
            foreach ($listArr as $uid) {
                $page = $tsfe->sys_page->getPage($uid);

                if($page['doktype'] == PageRepository::DOKTYPE_SYSFOLDER)
                    break;

                if (!$page['is_siteroot']) {
                    $pidList[] = $page['pid'];
                }
            }
        }
        return implode(',', $pidList);
    }

}
```